# Unrecognized Guid format

Tags: c#

I am working on c# application where i am getting this error.

Here is Stack Track of error:

> Stack Trace:
>           at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String
>   failureArgumentName, Exception innerException) at
>   System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult&
>   result) at System.Guid..ctor(String g) at
>   Projects_AddProject.wizCreateProject_ActiveStepChanged(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnActiveStepChanged(Object source,
>   EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.MultiViewActiveViewChanged(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.MultiView.OnActiveViewChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.MultiView.set_ActiveViewIndex(Int32
>   value) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.set_ActiveStepIndex(Int32
>   value) at Projects_AddProject.proxy_Navigate(Object sender,
>   HistoryEventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RaiseNavigate(HistoryEventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.LoadHistoryState(String serverState) at
>   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)

From the error  its happening when its converting the string to guid. The method this occurs is wizCreateProject_ActiveStepChanged.It looks some Guid Conversion issue.

Here is method that generate error:

```
protected void wizCreateProject_ActiveStepChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
              switch (wizCreateProject.ActiveStepIndex)
        {
                       case 0:
                if (rbFrmTemp.Checked)
                {
                    int tenantID = TenantUtils.getTenantId(Page);
                    EzProject templateProject = DBAccessProjects.GetProject(tenantID, new Guid(ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue));

                    txNme.Text = templateProject.ProjectName;
                    txDesc.Text = templateProject.ProjectDescription;
                    CheckLoadWorkType(tenantID, ddlWrkType);

                    if (templateProject.WorkTypeID != null)
                    {
                        ListItem workItem = ddlWrkType.Items.FindByValue(templateProject.WorkTypeID.ToString());
                        if (workItem != null)
                        {
                            ddlWrkType.SelectedValue = templateProject.WorkTypeID.ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (templateProject.ProjectType == (int)ProjectType.Reoccurring)
                    {
                        CheckGroupedRadioButton(rbReoccurring);
                        txBilFreq.Text = templateProject.BillingFrequency.ToString();
                        if (templateProject.LastDate != null)
                        {
                            txtDate.Text = ((DateTime)templateProject.LastDate).ToShortDateString();
                        }
                        ListItem prdItem = ddlBilPrd.Items.FindByValue(templateProject.BillingPeriod);
                        if (prdItem != null)
                        {
                            ddlBilPrd.SelectedValue = prdItem.Value;
                        }
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(upPnlProject, typeof(UpdatePanel), upPnlProject.ClientID, "TypeChanged();", true);

                        wizCreateProject.ActiveStepIndex = 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wizCreateProject.ActiveStepIndex = 3;
                    }
                    BtnADD.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (rbReoccurring.Checked)
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(upPnlProject, typeof(UpdatePanel), upPnlProject.ClientID, "TypeChanged();", true);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                txNme.Focus();
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(upPnlProject, typeof(UpdatePanel), upPnlProject.ClientID, "InitNames();", true);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the value of `ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth it shows value like this :   <option value="7590aab2-29b9-4262-9982-4403ca7b52f2">Managed Services Agreement</option>      Thanks

Comment: Well, this certainly isn't a valid GUID. You need to make sure to only pass the value of the `value` attribute. And not the rest.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth what i need to modify in code.Can you please help?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth are you there?

Comment: This is not a coding service. Have you tried anything yourself? One example would be to parse this into a XDocument and extract the value by means of LINQ to XML. Another necessary thought should be if the `SelectedValue` really has the correct value. Should it really have that XML as its value or should the value really be only the GUID?

Answer (score 3):

The error is here:

```
EzProject templateProject 
         = DBAccessProjects.GetProject(tenantID, new Guid(ddlProjTemplates.SelectedValue));
```

You can see that internally the Guid constructor is using `Guid.TryParse()` which is what you should be doing.  I would add a validator to the ddlProjTemplates to make it required and you also need to make sure that it only contains valid Guids.

Comment: ddlProjectTemplates have this type of vaues      <option value="7590aab2-29b9-4262-9982-4403ca7b52f2">Managed Services Agreement</option>

Comment: You probably aren't requiring the user to pick a value and they are sending you an empty string

Comment: I agree with matt-dot-net.  Most likely you have a bunch of legitimate guids, BUT you are passing an empty-string in the error-case...and an empty-string won't parse as a Guid.  Use the TryParse and throw an exception or provide a different code-block for empty-string selections.

Comment: PS.  Please mark this as "the answer" if it resolved or help you resolve the issue........